# Return image from Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Beacon(string value)
{
    var dir = Server.MapPath("/Content/Images/Sprites/");
    var path = Path.Combine(dir, "logo.png");
    return base.File(path, "image/png");

}
```

Generated HTML:

```
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://localhost:38315/Beacon/999">
```

However the image is not displayed. In Chrome it's a small box with grey borders and in MS Edge there is a box with an "X" in it which I assume is the "File not found" image.

I have tried returning different images (to make sure the first one was not corrupt), several Content Types but without any luck.

I'm sure that the different files that I have tried with exists.

I read this post: [ASP.Net MVC - Img Src Server Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803659/asp-net-mvc-img-src-server-path)

I have tried this:

```
return File("~/images/beacon.png", "image/png");
```

I have tried returning a Base64 string but with no luck.

When I run this code it states that the file do exist:

```
var dir = Server.MapPath("/images");
var path = Path.Combine(dir, "beacon.png");
var res = System.IO.File.Exists(path);
return base.File(path, "image/png");
```

How can I return a simple image through a Controller?

*** Willy David Jr Suggestion ***

```
public ActionResult Beacon(string value) {

var path =  Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Sprites/")) + "logo.png";
var theFile = new FileInfo(path);

if (theFile.Exists) {
    return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path), "image/png");
    //or return base.File(path, "image/png");
}
    return this.HttpNotFound();                
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it hit the action when debugging? Check that the path given to the image is maps to an action. Also, do a `System.IO.File.Exsits(path)` on the path and make sure that the derived path is there. Chances are that you are generating the path wrong.

Comment: @Nkosi Updated answer. "res" is true i.e. it seems to exist.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following and see if it applies to your situation.

```
public ActionResult Beacon(string value) {
    var dir = Server.MapPath("/Content/Images/Sprites/");
    var path = Path.Combine(dir, "logo.png");
    var theFile = new FileInfo(path);
    if (theFile.Exists) {
        return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path), "image/png");
    }
    return this.HttpNotFound();                
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. It returns en error image i.e "theFile.Exists" goes through. =/

Comment: Yes, sir I am. And it states the same that the file do exists and gives a path that do exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
public ActionResult Beacon(string value) {

var path =  Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Sprites/")) + "logo.png";
var theFile = new FileInfo(path);

if (theFile.Exists) {
    return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path), "image/png");
    //or return base.File(path, "image/png");
}
    return this.HttpNotFound();                
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately not. I edited my question and added some screenshots using your solution.