# Display multiple images from database using view model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database

I want to display several images in my view . So I upload images to file system and information about images store in database. I have a table relation one to many ( `Furniture` is primary table , `FurnitureImages` where i save image's info). Also I use View model.

But images doesn't want to display because something wrong with passing parameter `List<SecondaryImages>` in Edit GET method. I can't write `model.SecondaryImages. = ...` because it is `List` Here is my part of code.

Controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    ....
    var furniture = db.Furnitures.Find(id);
    FurnitureVM model = new FurnitureVM();
    model.Name = furniture.Name;
    .... // set other properties of the view model based on the data model
    FurnitureImages main = furniture.Images.Where(x => x.IsMainImage).FirstOrDefault();
    foreach(var i in model.SecondaryImages)
    {
        i.DisplayName = main.DisplayName;
        i.Path = main.Path;
        i.IsMainImage = main.IsMainImage;
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Data models

```
public class Furniture
{
    ....
    public virtual ICollection<FurnitureImages> Images { get; set; }
}
public class FurnitureImages
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public bool IsMainImage { get; set; } // this determines if its the main or secondary image
    public int FurnitureId { get; set; } // navigation property
    public virtual Furniture Furniture { get; set; }
}
```

View models

```
public class FurnitureVM
{
    public FurnitureVM()
    {
        ....
        this.SecondaryImages = new List<ImageVM>();
    }       
    ....
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> SecondaryFiles { get; set; }
    public List<ImageVM> SecondaryImages { get; set; }        
}
public class ImageVM
{ 
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public bool IsMainImage { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.SecondaryImages.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SecondaryImages[i].Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SecondaryImages[i].Path)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SecondaryImages[i].DisplayName)
    <img src="@Url.Content(Model.SecondaryImages[i].Path)" />
}
```

Comment: You also need to include you models for `Furniture` (just a few properties in including the collection property for the images) and `FurnitureImages`

Comment: @StephenMuecke  sorry don't understand your sentence , you mean in  <code>foreach(var images in model.SecondaryImages)

Comment: Never mind - I'll edit your question with the necessary code based on your last question (give me 5 min) and then I'll add an answer.

Comment: Can you double check my edit - the data models I have added and confirm its correct. (and I deleted the POST method since its not relevant to your question)

Comment: @StephenMuecke it's ok , i try writing your code now

Comment: NO - all I want you to do is check that the code I added for the data models are correct (I will add the answer as soon as you confirm that)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes , it is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `foreach` loop in the GET method is iterating through the `SecondaryImages` property of your view model which is just an empty collection. You need to iterate through the `Images` collection of your data model, and initialize new instances of `ImageVM` and add then to the view model `SecondaryImages` collection.

```
Furniture furniture = db.Furnitures.Find(id);
IEnumerable<FurnitureImages> images = furniture.Images; // all images
FurnitureImages mainImage = images.Where(x => x.IsMainImage).FirstOrDefault();
IEnumerable<FurnitureImages> secondaryImages = images.Where(x => !x.IsMainImage);
FurnitureVM model = new FurnitureVM()
{
    Name = furniture.Name,
    .... // set other properties
    MainImage = new ImageVM()
    {
        Id = mainImage.Id,
        DisplayName = mainImage.DisplayName,
        ....
    },
    SecondaryImages = secondaryImages.Select(x => new ImageVM()
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Path = x.Path,
        DisplayName = x.DisplayName
    }).ToList()
};
return View(model);
```

Note the `bool IsMainImage` property in your view model seems unnecessary unless your generating a checkbox for it in the view.

I addition, I recommend you follow convention and rename `FurnitureImages` (plural) to `FurnitureImage` since it describes a single object.

Comment: thanks I'll try ypur code in the morning and if it wil work  i accepted your asnwer. Thank you very much

Comment: I can't write MainImage.Id = mainImage.Id, in the brackets { } in FurnitureVM ,  so do it without brackets ??

Comment: yay , it's work , thanks, but i feel i will ask next questions about post methods , sorry  :)

Comment: I keep an eye out for it :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42309670/upload-new-images-in-edit-post-method?noredirect=1#comment71774151_42309670 I really need your help , explain how I must to write my code , correctly , thanks

Comment: Bit busy just now. I will have a look in 30 min or so.